# How to move older clickhouse partitions to S3 disk

Tags: amazon-s3, clickhouse

I'm currently starting to work with clickhouse for our in-house analytics system, but it looks like there are no automated ways to configure policies for data retention. The only thing I saw was the `ALTER ... MOVE PARTITION` (https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition/#alter_move-partition), but it looks like the process has to be manual / implemented in our application layer.

My objective is to move data older than 3 months directly to an S3 cluster for archival and price reasons, while still being able to query it.

Is there any native way to do so directly in clickhouse with storage policies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-and-s3-compatible-object-storage

S3 volume + TTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer was based out of @Denny Crane's comment: https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-and-s3-compatible-object-storage, where I did put comments where there were not enough explanations, and keeping it in the event that the link dies.

- 1. Add your S3 disk to a new configuration file (Let's say `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/storage.xml`:

```html
<yandex>
  <storage_configuration>
    <disks>
      <!-- This tag is the name of your S3-emulated disk, used for the rest of this tutorial -->
      <your_s3>
        <type>s3</type>
        <!-- Set this to the endpoint of your S3-compatible provider -->
        <endpoint>https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com</endpoint>
        <!-- Set this to your access key ID provided by your provider -->
        <access_key_id>*****</access_key_id>
        <!-- Set this to your access key Secret provided by your provider -->
        <secret_access_key>*****</secret_access_key>
      </your_s3>
    </disks>
  <!-- Don't leave this file yet! We still have things to do there -->
  ...
  </storage_configuration>
</yandex>
```

- 2. Add a storage policy for your data storage:

```html
<!-- Put this after the three dots in the snippet above -->
<policies>
  <shared>
    <volumes>
      <default>
        <!-- Default is the disk that is present in the default config -->
        <disk>default</disk>
      </default>
      <your_s3>
        <disk>your_s3</disk>
      </your_s3>
    </volumes>
  </shared>
</policies>
```

Once that is done, you can create your tables with the following insert statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE visits (...)
ENGINE = MergeTree
TTL toStartOfYear(time) + interval 3 year to volume 'your_s3'
SETTINGS storage_policy = 'shared';
```

Where `shared` is your policy name, and `your_s3` is the name of your disk in that policy.

Comment: how to move back from s3 to default?